# how can I use the mysqldump correctly

Tags: mysql, database

I work with MySQL Server 5.5 and I have a problem in extracting my database,this is how I used this command:

```
mysql> mysqldump -uroot -pkail mybase > C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\b 
in\base.sql;
```

and this is the Error that I get:

```
ERROR: 
Unknown command '\P'. 
ERROR: 
Unknown command '\M'. 
ERROR: 
Unknown command '\M'. 
ERROR: 
Unknown command '\b'. 
Outfile disabled. 
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'mysq 
dump -uroot -pkail mybase > C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin' at 
line 1
```

how can I resolve the problem and thanks for any help :)

Comment: this kind of questions are on the chapter "i just copy n paste and i dont care about the text on the first web page I found on google", please solve my laziness

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Mysqldump should not be executed from within MySQL. It is a separate command.

Exit the MySQL console and try it there.

---

If you look in C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin, you'll see mysql.exe, and you'll also see mysqldump.exe. So mysqldump is a completely separate executable from mysql.exe, which is why you run it from the Windows command line, not from the MySQL console.

Comment: thanks Travesty3 :) ,but I have an other question pleaze is there a way to import my database again with windows console

Comment: Open the MySQL console, create the database (`CREATE DATABASE mybase;`), switch to that database (`use mybase;`), and import from the file using this command: `source "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin\base.sql";`